# CCActionAnimate runAction: ...but not running

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

I have a CCNode class that looks like this:

```
#import "CCAnimation.h"
#import "Gameplay.h"
#import "ZAFSingletonCenter.h"

@interface Gameplay ()
{
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) CCSprite *character;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CCAction *talkAction;

@end

@implementation Gameplay{

    NSMutableString *gesture;
    NSString *characterName;

    NSString *plist;
    NSString *gestureSprite;
    NSString *framefilename;

}

- (void)regresar {
    CCScene *mainScene = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"MainScene"];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:mainScene];
}

- (void)didLoadFromCCB {


    ZAFSingletonCenter *temporal = [ZAFSingletonCenter sharedManager];
    characterName = temporal.personajeActual;

    gesture = [@"fotos" mutableCopy];

    plist = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.plist",characterName,gesture];
    gestureSprite = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png",characterName,gesture];
    framefilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@_%@_",characterName,gesture,characterName,gesture];
    [self loadGesture:characterName withGesture:gesture];

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:plist];
    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:gestureSprite];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];


    // *** This block should be moved outside the init or didLoadFromCCB
    // *** and to the moveCharacter:withGesture method... once I make it work

    NSMutableArray *actionFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=1001; i<=1020; i++) {
        [actionFrames addObject:
         [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.png",framefilename,i]]];
        //NSLog(@"%@%d.png",_framefilename,i);
    }

    CCAnimation *gestureAction = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:actionFrames delay:0.0666f];

    CGSize viewSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize];
    NSString *spriteCover = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@_%@_1011.png",characterName,gesture,characterName,gesture];
    self.character = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:spriteCover];
    self.character.position = ccp(viewSize.width/2, viewSize.height/2);
    [spriteSheet addChild:self.character z:99];
    self.talkAction = [CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                       [CCActionAnimate actionWithAnimation:gestureAction]];


    [self.character runAction:self.talkAction];

    NSString *logMessage = self.character.debugDescription;
    NSLog(@"---> %@",logMessage);

    NSLog(@"---> %d",self.character.isRunningInActiveScene);

    NSString *gestureMessage = gestureAction.debugDescription;
    NSLog(@"---> %@",gestureMessage);

    NSString *actionMessage = self.talkAction.debugDescription;
    NSLog(@"---> %@",actionMessage);


    // *** ending the block to be taken to the moveCharacter:withGesture method

}


- (void)actionA {
    //testingButton A action
    NSLog(@"A");
    [self.character stopAction:self.talkAction];
}
- (void)actionB {
    //testingButton B action
    NSLog(@"B");
    [self.character runAction:self.talkAction];

}

@end
```

This should have an animated character in the middle of the screen and it does on an empty project.  But when I include this on the actual project the animation stays paused on the frame I define as "spriteCover". No errors at all, just not playing the animation.

I have tried using -(id)init instead of -(void)didLoadFromCCB but is the same.  I have traced several steps (you can see log section on the code above) and everything looks fine to me. Here are the printed lines:

```
---> <CCSprite = 0x15693a50 | 
     Rect = (281.50,568.50,147.00,268.00) | 
     tag = (null) | atlasIndex = 0>

---> 0

---> <CCAnimation = 0x15692de0 | 
     frames=20, totalDelayUnits=20.000000, 
     delayPerUnit=0.066600, loops=1>

---> <CCActionRepeatForever = 0x15694470 | Tag = -1>
```

I added two buttons that trigger actionA and actionB and when tapping twice on the actionB I get an error (as expected) because `reason: 'runAction: Action already running'`

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172602/runaction-not-working-within-a-ccnode), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798404/iphone-runaction-not-running), [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841265/sprite-frame-animation-cocos2d-3-0?lq=1) and several other sources but haven't yet solved the problem.

Comment: Anything printed in the log? Maybe the files couldn't be found, maybe you didn't add them to the project (or the correct target)? Does your format string correctly match the filename, including upper/lowercase and the number format?

Comment: Thank you for your reply LearnCocos2D.  Yes, you can see what the result on the NSLog lines above.  I did some testing changing the paths and filenames on purpose to see the "file to found" errors printed on the console.

I have to say there is no error that stops the application itself.  Is just that the animation stays paused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to document my solution, the way I solved the problem was getting the UIViewController preceding the CCScene with the animation.  I noticed that when loading after a CCScene everything worked perfectly but when loading after a UIViewController the animation didn't start.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that you want to recycle your `CCAction` talkAction for multiple use cases.

You have to create a separate `CCAction` instance for each time you call `runAction` on something.

A simple way to solve this would be to overwrite the getter of `talkAction` to always return a new `CCAction`.